# Textbox onKeyPress in Firefox not working

Tags: javascript, firefox

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>   
        function handleKeyPress(evt) {   
            var nbr;   
            var nbr = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : evt.which;   
            alert(nbr);  
            return true; 
        }   
    </script> 
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type=text name="txt" onkeypress="handleKeyPress();">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is working perfectly with IE but not in Firefox. I'm using IE8 and Firefox 3

Answer (score 4):

You missed to pass `event` object to `handleKeyPress()` call.

```
<input type="text" name="txt" onkeypress="handleKeyPress(event);">
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function onlyNumbers(evt)
{
var nbr;
var nbr = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : evt.which;

if ((nbr >= 48 && nbr <= 57) || nbr == 8) 
{
    return true;
}
else 
{
    return false;
}
}
</script>
```

html is

onkeypress="return onlyNumbers(event);"

Answer (score 0):

```
function getFilter(e, obj){ 
    e=e||event;
    console.log(e.ctrlKey);
    if (e.keyCode===10 || (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode===13)){
        //works on chrome + firefox filter for ctl+enter
    }
}
```